# New 5.4 array short array syntax: Good practice?

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, standards

I'd like to use the new short array syntax:

```
# Old syntax
$foo = array(
  'key1' => 'value1',
  'key2' => 'value2',
  'key3' => 'value3',
  'key4' => array(
    'key1' => 'value2',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3',
    'key4' => 'value4',
  ),
);

# New Syntax
$bar = [
  'key1' => 'value1',
  'key2' => 'value2',
  'key3' => 'value3',
  'key4' => [
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3',
    'key4' => 'value4',
  ],
];
```

Is that syntax considered as a good practice right now? Or should I stay with the old syntax?

Comment: You are safe until you downgrade..

Comment: Will you distribute your code to others? If yes then it depends on whether you want to force your users to upgrade to php 5.4+. If not, do whatever you like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually good practice is related to the logic of your code and not to it's syntax, There's a reason they made that new array syntax and that reason is: faster coding and easier to read.
So good practice is irrelevant here.